# React useEffect memory leak, second argument

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am fetching data inside of useEffect, with intention to update useState with data obtained. I kept getting null inside of oneCrypto state value even though console log showed that data was received. Realized it has to do with second argument missing in useState. When  add [] empty array, my oneCrypto shows null. When I set [oneCrypto] inside the array, as a dependency, my app crashes - too many requests, console log prints data received over and over and I don't understand why... help please.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
export default function SingleCrypto() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [oneCrypto, setOneCrypto] = useState(null)
    const { id } = useParams()
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getOneCrypto() {
            try {
                const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
                const response = await fetch(proxyurl +
                    "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info?id=" +
                    id,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            
                        }
                    }
                )
                const data = await response.json()
                const mydata = data.data;
                setOneCrypto(mydata)
                console.log(oneCrypto)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        getOneCrypto()
    }, [oneCrypto])



    return <>
        <h1>I am Single Crypto page</h1>
    </>
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning a function inside `useEffect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setOneCrypto` causes a rerender and since oneCrypto has changed since the previous render `useEffect` is called again and the process restarts.  Inside the `useEffect` where you call `console.log(oneCrypto)` is happening before the value has been updated because the update happens between renders.

Try removing oneCrypto from the array passed in the second argument and call console.log outside your useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is:

```
1) |--> your async function call setOneCrypto ---| 
2) |--  new value of oneCrypto call useEffect <--|
```

Might be you want one request if oneCrypto is `null`:

```
!oneCrypto && getOneCrypto();
```